# Why are there still left handed people?

Tags: neuroscience, evolutionary-psychology

About 90% of all people are right handed. About 10% of people are left handed. So why has left handedness persisted for so long throughout human evolution? Why does it stick around? What are the best psychological/neuroscience theories we have?

Comment: In case there isn't' a specific one, this applies: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont

Comment: See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2666081/ for a specific list/review.

Comment: @Fizz It would probably be better to answer with a summary of the paper you linked rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: @BryanKrause: If/when I have the time to write it, yes.

Comment: @Fizz I'm like you and like to be helpful and get caught myself doing what you've done here, but I've been admonished for it as well so I'm carrying it forward :) Part of the issue is that when you give an incomplete answer in a comment in the SE model, it a) discourages others from answering (you've basically answered already, they don't want to steal your answer), b) encourages the asker to not bother accepting a future good answer (they may have no need to return to their question since it's already been answered), and c) bypasses the up/down voting system for answers.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I don't mind "stealing my thunder" by properly answering (based on) a mere link-only comment.